# Suggestion regarding max concurrent consumer

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a spring integration application and I am using message driver adapter to consume messages from external systems. To handle the messages concurrently I have setup concurrent (5) and maximum concurrent consumers (20) which is working fine.

But for production scenario I wanted to fine tune it further. I just want to understand that if we have any standard suggestion regarding how much we can increase this maximum concurrent consumer to? I understand that this is purely dependent on the application and how much traffic is coming to it but I hope there should be some standard process to figure out this number. If we blindly increase this number to a random value like 1000 than it might lead to resource starvation, conflicts etc so I am trying to understand the process of how to go about fine tuning this property.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard process as there is no standard performance requirement. It all depends on your SLA and performant system is the one that *meets* your SLA (as there is no such thing as *beats* SLA).
The main caveat when it comes to concurrent consumers is the order of messages. Basically once you introduced more then one consumer you can not and should not assume any guarantees of message ordering.